# how to write test cases for authenticated urls in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-testing

I am using flask with mongoengine and Login Manager for session maintaining. I want to write test cases for authenticated views. can any one help/suggestions regarding this.

Comment: Just send request with the cookie you get after your login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I recommend using [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/), and the [flask-pytest](http://pytest-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library which contains some great convenience features to make all of this easier.

**flask-pytest** comes out of the box with a `client` fixture, which, per the docs, refers to [Flask.test_client](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.test_client)

What you want to do is mimic a valid session *(e.g. however you app is validating that a user is "logged in")*.

Here is how to do this without any supporting libraries:

```
import app
from flask import url_for

def test_authenticated_route():
    app.testing = True
    client = app.test_client()

    with client.session_transaction() as sess:
        # here you can assign whatever you need to
        # emulate a "logged in" user...
        sess["user"] = {"email": "test_user@example.com"}

    # now, you can access "authenticated" endpoints
    response = client.get(url_for(".protected_route"))
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

This is also discussed in the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#accessing-and-modifying-sessions).

Comment: Thanks.
I was so confused in session. now my doubt got cleared.